# Reading from std::ofstream line by line (but not from the file)

Tags: c++, inputstream, ifstream, outputstream, ofstream

in my project I need to use the following library ([OMPL](http://ompl.kavrakilab.org/index.html)). I am interested in particular in a the member function printAsMatrix(std::ofstream &out) which outputs data to a terminal or to a file. Here the [function](http://ompl.kavrakilab.org/classompl_1_1geometric_1_1PathGeometric.html#a3bb5066416f1bc696c205dc323f93d79):

```
 void ompl::geometric::PathGeometric::printAsMatrix(std::ostream &out) const
 {
  const base::StateSpace* space(si_->getStateSpace().get());
  std::vector<double> reals;
  for (unsigned int i = 0 ; i < states_.size() ; ++i)
  {
  space->copyToReals(reals, states_[i]);
  std::copy(reals.begin(), reals.end(), std::ostream_iterator<double>(out, " "));
  out << std::endl;
  }
  out << std::endl;
 }
```

but I need those the outputted values in thier original form, as double. For this reason I thought to read them though the `ifstringstream` library using the following function implemented on my own:

```
std::ofstream solution_matrix; 

pg->printAsMatrix( solution_matrix ); // generate the solution with OMPL and copy them into "solution_matrix"

std::istringstream istr; // generate a variable 
std::string buffer;      // the buffer in which the string is going to be copied t

double var1, var2; // dummies variables

while( getline( solution_matrix, buffer ) ) {
   istr.str( buffer );
   istr >> var1 >> var2 >> var3 >> var4 >> var5 >> var6 >> var7;
   std::cout >> var1 >> var2; // did you copy all data!?!? Show me please!
}
```

I get a lot of compilation errors because of the `getline` function which accepts only std::ifstream data.

So heir what I did as a temporary workaround:

1. Created a new `ifstream` variable:

   std::ifstream input_matrix;
2. Tried to copy the outputted matrix into the input:

   solution_matrix << input_matrix;
3. call the getline function with the new variable:

   getline( input_matrix, buffer );

I have now no compilation errors but the code simply doesn't work. Plus I m not really sure that I did it in the right way.

Looking around I found lot of example using a file to copy at first the data and then reading from the same file with `ifstream`. Something like:

```
  // Print the solution path to a file
  std::ofstream ofs("path.dat");
  pg->printAsMatrix(ofs);
```

But to do that I need to create a new file, save it on the hard disk and then open it a second time using `ifstream`:

```
std::ifstream file;
file.open( "path.dat" );
```

This way works but I really don't want to create a file.
Is there a way to do it:

1. without creating a file;
2. reading the matrix line by line (I will sort out the values);

Many thank in advance

Comment: I would think a full-fledged [`std::stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) would get you what you want, but its hard saying from your description. Worth a try, anyway.

Comment: Thanks Whoz. could you provide an example please?

Comment: Not really, since I'm not sure what you're trying to do. Bottom line though would be to forego the on-disk file stream and do a`printAsMatrix(ss)` to a `std::stringstream`, then position the get-pos to where you want and start slurping in data via regular stream ops (in theory). You won't get your line-by-line (hard to do that without a custom streambuf derivative) but you will get your in-memory goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `std::stringstream` with `std::getline`, which can be passed to your function as the `ostream` parameter. For example:

```
std::stringstream solution_matrix; 

pg->printAsMatrix( solution_matrix ); 

std::string line;
while (std::getline(solution_matrix, line)) {
    std::cout << line << std::endl;
}
```

Also, your `<<` are the wrong way round in your cout statement:

```
std::cout >> var1 >> var2;
```

Should be:

```
std::cout << var1 << var2;
```

**EDIT**

To clarify this here is a full example to show this working:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

void func(std::ostream&, const std::vector<double>&);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
  std::stringstream solution_matrix; 
  std::vector<double> example;
  for (int i=0; i<10; ++i) {
    example.push_back(i);
  }

  func(solution_matrix, example);

  std::string line;
  while (std::getline(solution_matrix, line)) {
    std::cout << line << std::endl;
  }

}

void func(std::ostream& out, const std::vector<double>& data)
{
  std::copy(data.begin(), data.end(), std::ostream_iterator<double>(out, "\n"));
}
```

Here `func` is similar to your `printAsMatrix()` function, in that it writes to an ostream. The vector `example` contains the values 0-9. The output is:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Comment: Many thanks. But are you sure? Because I get the following error from the compiler: `error: ‘std::ofstream’ has no member named ‘str’`

Comment: That error suggests you've made a typo. It should be str, not srt.

Comment: I've also changed my ofstream to ostream, which matches the function deceleration you gave in your answer.

Comment: Are you sure? std::ostream is just a frame and cannot be constructed as far as I know...

Comment: Anyway...I think you are not right because I get the same error (even with ostream - no **f** ) from the compiler because it has not a .str() member function. Even [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/) I coudln't find any function like that

Comment: I've changed the answer to use rdbuf() which should be available for ostream (I can't test it, I'm posting this from my phone). It might be possible to miss the stringstream step and just read into an istringstream.

Comment: I thank you a lot for your efforts but it doesn't work... Compilation errors

Comment: @Dave The simple thing I overlooked was that you can simply pass a stringstream to your printAsMatrix function, this stringstream can then be processed with getline. I've updated my answer to show this and included a working example program.